# How to use "Jenssegers\Mongodb" in User model - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, model, moloquent

I want to use ["Jenssegers\Mongodb" package](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) in a Laravel 5.5 app.
The [package documentation](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) tells to use:

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model {}
```

instead of:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model {}
```

But, in`User` model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable{}
```

and in "Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User" class (what 'Authenticatable' refers to) it's using `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` not `Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model`.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393753/use-mongodb-with-laravel-5-3) to extend what 'Authenticatable' extends directly in my model instead of extending 'Authenticatable' itself, so that I can `use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;`

**Is there another better solution or should I make it like that??**

Comment: Have you tried the part [Extensions Auth](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#auth) on that same page?

Comment: @kerbholz  I think I should use this only if I'm using password reminders as it's mentioned there. It doesn't relate to my problem.

Answer (score 3):

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

then

class User extends Authenticatable